# c++ module for python (32bit/64bit)

Tags: python, c++

I have read the following tutorial [Write c++ extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) and wrote a simple function, however i'm on a 64 bit linux (and I don't know how to create a 32 bit jail for python) so I launched python3.6 64 bit and imported the module and <s>everything worked</s>.

Actually I had compiled pybind11 as 64 bit and the same for the plugin,
but everything still works as 64 bit.

But according to the tutorial

> Working with C++ requires that you use a 32-bit Python interpreter (Python 3.6 or above recommended).

So why should I use a 32 bit interpreter if I can build and import my extension as 64bit?

Also can this cause any issues when building the application to an executable and including the module?

The c++ extension (the windows version is shown below the linux is the same but with process_vm_writev instead of WriteProccessMemory):

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>


int main(char* procID, int address, int newValue) {

    DWORD pID = atoi(procID);
    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);


    if (handle == NULL) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        LPVOID mem_addr = (LPVOID)address;
        std::cout << "address: " << address << "\n";
        std::cout << "mem_addr: " << mem_addr << "\n";
        WriteProcessMemory(handle, mem_addr, &newValue, sizeof(newValue), 0);
    }

    return 0;
}

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(c_writter, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 memory writter plugin"; // optional module docstring

    m.def("writter", &main, "A function that writes to process memory");
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
project(cnake)

find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

if( $ENV{BUILD_TARGET} STREQUAL "linux")
    pybind11_add_module(c_writter lin_source.cpp)
elseif( $ENV{BUILD_TARGET} STREQUAL "windows" )
    pybind11_add_module(c_writter win_source.cpp)
endif()
```

This on windows produces a .pyd module and on linux a .so and while I haven't tested it on windows if I import the module to my 64 bit python on linux it runs as expected.

Comment: When building the module, you're going to want to link to the include and lib files of the specific python installation that will run the python code that imports the module you build.